# Difficulty with SQL and WPDB in particular in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm Stumped

I have 1/2 a dozen queries that all return expected results in MySQL Workbench, however, return nothing when called from WPDB.
I have tested WPDB works with very simple select statements, however, when they get more difficult WPDB doesn't like what I'm feeding it. I have tried for 2 days before turning here to ask - sadly I get no errors from WPDB just no results.

The query below returns me a stock date that any future orders will be able to ship.  If run through myself.  But return empty arrays in WPDB.

I understand this SQL needs some work, needs to be run through prepare and should be using the WPDB prefix - All this tidy up will come if I can get it working.

I have found that by simply leaving off the where clause I get a result - so this is where I have been focussing.  CAN ANYONE SEE WHAT I HAVE DONE WRONG? or MOST WRONG?

```
Select stocketa as NextDispatch From
(
Select ETA as stocketa,(@runtot := @runtot + q1.QtyInbound) AS QtyInbound_rt, (q1.SOH * -1) as InverseSOH FROM
(
Select  pm1.meta_value AS ETA,  OIM1.meta_value AS QtyInbound, pm2.meta_value as SOH
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID  AND pm1.meta_key    = '_expected_at_location_date')
LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_items OI ON ( OI.order_id = p.id)
LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM1 ON (OIM1.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM1.meta_key='_qty' )
LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM2 ON (OIM2.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM2.meta_key='_product_id' )
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ( pm2.post_id = OIM2.meta_value and pm2.meta_key = '_stock')
Where OIM2.meta_value = 5734 and p.post_status='atum_pending'

Order By ETA ASC
) as q1
) as q2
WHERE q2.QtyInbound_rt > q2.InverseSOH
LIMIT 1
```

This is how I am attempting to run it with WPDB  (My first attempt at use of WP and WPDB so ... please dont laugh

```
$ProdID = get_the_ID();
echo ("Prod ID:" . $ProdID);
if(!defined('DIEONDBERROR')) define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );
global $wpdb;


$selectString ="
select ETA as inStockETA, QtyInbound_rt as QI,InverseSOH as ISOI FROM ( Select ETA,(@runtot := @runtot + q1.QtyInbound) AS QtyInbound_rt, (q1.SOH * -1) as InverseSOH 
FROM ( Select pm1.meta_value AS ETA, OIM1.meta_value AS QtyInbound, pm2.meta_value as SOH FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID AND pm1.meta_key = '_expected_at_location_date') LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_items OI ON ( OI.order_id = p.id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM1 ON (OIM1.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM1.meta_key='_qty' ) 
LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM2 ON (OIM2.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM2.meta_key='_product_id' )
 LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ( pm2.post_id = OIM2.meta_value and pm2.meta_key = '_stock') 
Where OIM2.meta_value = 5734 and p.post_status='atum_pending' Order By ETA ASC 
) as q1 
) as q2 
WHERE q2.QtyInbound_rt > q2.InverseSOH LIMIT 1 
";

//$selectString = $wpdb->prepare($selectString,$ProdID);
echo("Select String:" . $selectString);

//$nextShip = $wpdb->get_results($selectString);
//$nextShip = $wpdb->get_results($selectString,ARRAY_A);


$wpdb->show_errors();
$nextShip = $wpdb->get_results($selectString);
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

After putting in DIEONDBERROR ()
The output is :

```
Prod ID:5734Select String: select ETA as inStockETA, QtyInbound_rt as QI,InverseSOH as ISOI FROM ( Select ETA,(@runtot := @runtot + q1.QtyInbound) AS QtyInbound_rt, (q1.SOH * -1) as InverseSOH FROM ( Select pm1.meta_value AS ETA, OIM1.meta_value AS QtyInbound, pm2.meta_value as SOH FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID AND pm1.meta_key = '_expected_at_location_date') LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_items OI ON ( OI.order_id = p.id) LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM1 ON (OIM1.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM1.meta_key='_qty' ) LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM2 ON (OIM2.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM2.meta_key='_product_id' ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ( pm2.post_id = OIM2.meta_value and pm2.meta_key = '_stock') Where OIM2.meta_value = 5734 and p.post_status='atum_pending' Order By ETA ASC ) as q1 ) as q2 WHERE q2.QtyInbound_rt > q2.InverseSOH LIMIT 1


WordPress database error: [] select ETA as inStockETA, QtyInbound_rt as QI,InverseSOH as ISOI FROM ( Select ETA,(@runtot := @runtot + q1.QtyInbound) AS QtyInbound_rt, (q1.SOH * -1) as InverseSOH FROM ( Select pm1.meta_value AS ETA, OIM1.meta_value AS QtyInbound, pm2.meta_value as SOH FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm1 ON ( pm1.post_id = p.ID AND pm1.meta_key = '_expected_at_location_date') LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_items OI ON ( OI.order_id = p.id) LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM1 ON (OIM1.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM1.meta_key='_qty' ) LEFT JOIN wp_atum_order_itemmeta OIM2 ON (OIM2.order_item_id =OI.order_item_id AND OIM2.meta_key='_product_id' ) LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm2 ON ( pm2.post_id = OIM2.meta_value and pm2.meta_key = '_stock') Where OIM2.meta_value = 5734 and p.post_status='atum_pending' Order By ETA ASC ) as q1 ) as q2 WHERE q2.QtyInbound_rt > q2.InverseSOH LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Have you tried with the second argument in the get_results method?           `$nextShip = $wpdb->get_results($selectString,ARRAY_A);`

Comment: Thanks, I had not.  there is still no results:

Answer (score 0):

To know what is happening exactly with your query, use the following piece of code:

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
$nextShip = $wpdb->get_results($selectString);
$wpdb->print_error();
$wpdb->hide_errors();
```

and let me know the generated output.

Comment: Cheers, I have done so and there is no additional output at all.

Comment: If you are running a WordPress multisite, you should to include the following constant definition in your website's code: define( 'DIEONDBERROR', true );

Comment: The DIEONDBERROR did help to see that there is an error!  I have update the Question to show error response

Comment: In the error code you have published the error array is empty [] that means your query does not have generated an error. You can try to include a var_dump for checking the query result: `var_dump($nextShip);`  Furthermore, you can try to use directly the  `$wpdb->query();` instead the `$wpdb->get_results();`

Comment: Mike, Many thanks -  I am used to all errors having a code of some sort!  I'll try the $wpdb->query() instead, however, have already decided to unload the database server from the difficult query and instead put the logic in PHP side.   I was butting my head against the wall for too long and it was hurting my little project so I had to find an alternate solution.   I intend to get to the bottom of why the original query was returning nothing - if I can I will clean up this question with the result in the hope it will be useful to someone in the future.

Comment: Mike - The ARRAY_A comment was very helpful in my alternate solution too!  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there are some syntax errors in your query:

- You have entered **JOI$** but the correct would be **JOIN**
- There is an extra **LEFT JOIN** before the **WHERE** clause that should not be there.

Please, check the query you are assigning to the *$selectString* variable.

Comment: Sorry, It was a formatting error, the $ is terminal or nano showing that there is more on the line that's not visible as word wrap is off. Fixed in original Q.

Comment: I had/have validated that if I echo out the $selectString, copy it and paste it into MYSQL it parses and returns expected results.